# Question about simple zero and complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I was  asked, suppose that p has a simple zero at $z_{0}$ that is a root of multiplicity $1$, and let $\gamma$ be a simple $C^{1}$ curve that encircles $z_{0}$

then what can be said about

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{p'(\phi)}{p(\phi)} d\phi$$

Im really not sure what can be said, I guess since the degree of the derivative will always be one less then the polynomial itself, we will essentially end up with a constant over more terms, but I dont know what can be said in general.

Update: So I followed the hints and such and I made some progress, but now I am actually even more confused. For example, the hint says, first try for example with $p(z)=z$, $p(z)=z^2$ or $p(z)=z^3$ but here is my issue, because the only roots of these is zero, and it is NOT simple.

Comment: Maybe your professor meant to write single zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mentioned that $p$ is a polynomial, or at least seems like you're making an assumption that was not asserted. But you do know $p(z)=(z-z_0)q(z)$ where $q(z_0)\neq 0$. So $p'(z) = q(z)+(z-z_0)q'(z)$ and

$$\int_\gamma \dfrac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz =\int_\gamma \dfrac{1}{z-z_0} + \dfrac{q'(z)}{q(z)} dz$$

Integrating those separately, you can use Cauchy's residue theorem for the first. The second will be zero as it is analytic (assuming $\gamma$ encircles no more zeros of $p$).

Comment: i get a final answer of 1?

Comment: @Quality yes, $2i\pi$ in DavidP integral, if and only if $p(z)$ has no more zeros inside $\gamma$, and if $\gamma$ is a simple contour, that is homotopic to a the circle $|z-z_0| = r$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
p(z) = c(z-z_0)(z-z_1)\cdots (z-z_n)
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
p'(z) = c(z-z_1)\cdots (z-z_n) + c(z-z_0)(z-z_2)\cdots (z-z_n) +\ldots + c(z-z_0)(z-z_1) \cdots (z-z_{n-1})
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \frac{1}{z-z_0} + \frac{1}{z-z_1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{z-z_n}.
\end{align}
Assume $\gamma$ only encircle $z_0$, then what can you say now?

Comment: Isnt that integral of 1/z-zo equal to i2pi?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what you get.

Comment: I get a final answer of 1